# sampling distribution for N(0,1) samples

Tags: self-study, normal-distribution, sampling

Here is an portion of my lecture notes from class, we are studying sampling distributions. I am confused on some of the examples that are showed in the attached picture.

[image]

For the first example, from my analysis its saying that the sample mean $\bar{x}= {1\over{n}} \sum_{i=1}^n x_i \sim N(0,1/n)$? Is that safe to assume or correct?

For the second example where $2\bar{x}\sim N(0,1)$,  I am completely lost.  I am not sure as to why this is true. Can someone please explain?

I understand part 3 since it was explained as a theorem s.t ${(n-1)S^2\over{v^2}} = {\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i-\bar{x})^2\over{v^2}} ~ \chi^2_{n-1}$. [here $i$ indicate $v$ as variance]

For the fourth example, I am uncertain as to where $\sqrt{S^2}$ or sample variance came from. I know that $T={Z\over{\sqrt{W/n}}}$ where $W~\chi^2$ with $n$ df and that $Z\sim N(0,1)$  where both Z and W are independent. So I guess I am confused as to how the $\sqrt{S^2}=\sqrt{W/n}$ where n is the sample size. (update I have found the explanation to this)

However I am still confused as to part 2. Can someone please explain part 2?

Comment: Did you forget to attach the picture?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance#Basic_properties

Answer (score 2):

In the first example, you are correct. While it's not explicitly stated, the examples seem to assume that the marks of the different students will be independent of one another (which seems fairly reasonable). The following are fairly well known results for $x_i \sim N(\mu_i, \sigma_i^2)$, where the $x_i$ are independent:

1. $\sum_{i=1}^n x_i \sim N(\sum_{i=1}^n\mu_i,\sum_{i=1}^n\sigma_i^2)$
2. $Cx_i \sim N(C\mu_i, C^2\sigma_i^2)$ where C is a constant

For the first two points, you just need to use these two facts (the second part just uses the second fact, setting C=2, $\sigma_i^2$=1/4).

You seem to get the rest, which is great :)